# A DLL should free heap memory only if the DLL is unloaded dynamically?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dll, entry-point, dllmain

Question Purpose: Reality check on the [MS docs of `DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain).

It is "common" knowledge that you shouldn't do too much in DllMain, there are definite things you must never do, some [best practises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

I now stumbled over a new gem in the docs, that makes little sense to me: (emph. mine)

> When handling `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, a DLL should free resources such as
>   heap memory only if the DLL is being unloaded dynamically (the
>   `lpReserved` parameter is NULL). If the process is terminating (the
>   lpvReserved parameter is non-NULL), **all threads in the process** except
>   the current thread either **have exited already or have been explicitly
>   terminated** by a call to the [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) function, which might leave
>   **some process resources such *as heaps* in an inconsistent state**. In this
>   case, it is not safe for the DLL to clean up the resources. Instead,
>   the DLL should allow the operating system to reclaim the memory.

Since global C++ objects are cleaned up during DllMain/DETACH, this would imply that global C++ objects must not free any dynamic memory, because the heap may be in an inconsistent state. / When the DLL is "linked statically" to the executable. / Certainly not what I see out there - global C++ objects (iff there are) of various (ours, and third party) libraries allocate and deallocate just fine in their destructors. (Barring other ordering bugs, o.c.)

**So, what specific technical problem is this warning aimed at?**

Since the paragraph mentions thread termination, could there be a heap corruption problem when some threads are not cleaned up correctly?

Comment: This kind of verbiage gets added when they had one too many support phone calls.  The only reason to document an undocumented parameter.  An example scenario is a programmer using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(), do something useful to help diagnose the crash, and then ExitProcess instead of TerminateProcess.  Always works when tested, bummer when in the real world the crash was caused by heap corruption and the heap lock is still held.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExitProcess` API in general does the follwoing:

- Enter Loader Lock critical section
- **lock** main process heap (returned by [`GetProcessHeap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-getprocessheap)) via  [`HeapLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heaplock)`(GetProcessHeap())` (ok, of course via `RtlLockHeap`) (this is very important step for avoid deadlock)
- then **terminate** all threads in process, except current (by call `NtTerminateProcess(0, 0)` )
- then call `LdrShutdownProcess` - inside this api loader walk by loaded module list and sends `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` with `lpvReserved` nonnull.
- finally call `NtTerminateProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), ExitCode )` which terminates the process.

The problem here is that threads **terminated** in arbitrary place. For example, thread can allocate or free memory from any heap and be inside heap critical section, when it terminated. As a result, if code during `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` tries to free a block from the same heap, it deadlocks when trying to enter this heap's critical section (if of course heap implementation use it).

Note that this does not affect the main process heap, because we call `HeapLock` for it **before** terminate all threads (except current). The purpose of this: We wait in this call until all another threads exit from process heap critical section and after we acquire the critical section, no other threads can enter it - because the main process heap is locked.

So, when we terminate threads after locking the main heap - we can be sure that no other threads that are killed are inside main heap critical section or heap structure in inconsistent state. Thanks to `RtlLockHeap` call. But this is related only to main process heap. Any other heaps in the process are not locked. So these *can* be in inconsistent state during `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` or can be exclusively acquired by an already terminated thread.

So - using `HeapFree` for `GetProcessHeap` or saying `LocalFree` is safe (however not documented) here.

Using `HeapFree` for any other heaps is *not* safe if `DllMain` is called during process termination.

Also if you use another custom data structures by several threads - it can be in inconsistent state, because another threads (which can use it) terminated in arbitrary point.

So this note is warning that when  *lpvReserved* parameter is *non-NULL* (what is mean *DllMain* is called during process termination) you need to be especially careful in clean up the resources. Anyway all internal memory allocations will be free by operation system when process died.

Comment: Awesome! What you write makes a lot of sense. May I inquire how you know how the `ExitProcess` function operates? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @MartinBa - this is very easy look under debugger. but sure no any formal documentation from ms

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to RbMm's excellent answer, I'll add a quote from `ExitProcess` that does a much better job - than the DllMain docs do - at explaining, why heap operation (or any operation, really) can be compromised:

> If one of the terminated threads in the process holds a lock and the
>   DLL detach code in one of the loaded DLLs attempts to acquire the same
>   lock, then calling `ExitProcess` results in a deadlock. In contrast, if
>   a process terminates by calling [TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess), the DLLs that the
>   process is attached to are not notified of the process termination.
>   Therefore, if you do not know the state of all threads in your
>   process, it is better to call `TerminateProcess` than `ExitProcess`. Note
>   that returning from the main function of an application results in a
>   call to `ExitProcess`.

So, it all boils down to: IFF you application has "runaway" threads that may hold *any* lock, the (CRT) heap lock being a prominent example, you have a big problem during shutdown, when you need to access the same structures (e.g. the heap), that your "runaway" threads are using.

Which just goes to show that you should shut down *all* your threads in a controlled way.