# How to abort global objects destruction from DllMain?

Tags: windows, global-variables, shared-libraries, exit, dllmain

I need to find a reliable way to skip the global object deinitialization that happens just after `DllMain` has been called with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

From the Microsoft [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices), we find a list of tasks that *you should never perform from within DllMain*, and that list does not contains [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess).

May I assume it is safe to call `ExitProcess` in this context? And what about the other standard C function [`_Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/exit-exit-exit?view=msvc-160) that should be used to terminate a process without completely cleaning the resources? Currently, I'm using `_Exit` and it seems to work properly.

Comment: Are your clients expecting to see their process die when they are calling `FreeLibrary`?

Comment: almost never need call `ExitProcess` from dll. question in *I need skip the global object deinitialization*  - this is why ?

Comment: @RbMm My need is related to this issue: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/869

Comment: @IInspectable Actually the DLL is not intended to be loaded with `LoadLibrary`/`FreeLibrary` by the clients.

Comment: call `_thrd.join();` from destructor (inside dll critical section) is always error

Comment: For further analysis, my question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53818859/a-dll-should-free-heap-memory-only-if-the-dll-is-unloaded-dynamically.